# JavaScript createElement

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

After the user has posted an `article` (AJAX), I want the article to update though AJAX.

The issue, however, is when there are no articles and the user creates the first one -- that means I need to create the `article-div` with all the logic within it (eg. loop).

I know how to create a simple element in JS, but how does one create something like this?

**`welcome#index`**

```
#article-div
    - @articles.each do |article|
        .ajax_load.article-content{ id: "article" }
```

**`articles/create.js.erb`**

```
if (!($('#article-div'))) {
    $('#article-div').append('<%= j render(@article) %>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the `length` of that jquery object,

```
if (!$('.article-content').length) {
```

Since a jquery object never be evaluated to `false`. And there is no need to invoke `.remove()` over an empty jquery object. You full code would be,

```
if (!$('.article-content').length) {
   $('#article-div').append('<%= j render(@article) %>');
}
```

Comment: I had a mistake in my code that might have confused you, I apologize. My question focused on the creation of a div in JS with the same logic (loop etc) that is within `article-div` on my `index` page.